# How do I get the first 5 lines of the top command and append to a file?

Tags: command-line, python

I know you can do this by using the following command:

```
top -b -n 1 | head -n 5
```

However, I am trying to store and append the data from the top file to a file which is done by the following:

```
top -b -n 1 | head -n 5 >> test.txt
```

(`> test.txt` replaces the current text and does not append.)

The above command is used in a python script as such:

```
process = subprocess.Popen('top -b -n 1 | head -n 5 >> htop-' + str(i)  + '.txt', shell=True)
```

The above is in a function which is called each second.

However, only the first iteration is stored. The data is not appended.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! The proposed line with `>>` redirection works for me, the `top` output is appended on the second run. The problem must be elsewhere in your script.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have a python script which runs the above top command using subprocess.popen in a function. The function itself is called every second (allowing the file to be appended every second). However, the file created only has the first iteration.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the relevant part of the script. The command line you presented works well in shell.

Comment: If the first iteration works then the issue would be in the script!

Comment: You may wish to post more of the Python on a suitable SE -- I suspect there's a logic error in your Python and you're only calling the `top` command once.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to appended periodically - you'll probably need some loop or something else to call that script more than once.
Here's an example with an infinite `while` loop:

```
while [ 1 ]; do
    top -b -n 1 | head -n 5 >> test.txt
    sleep 1
done
```

You can adjust how often it will be logged by changing the parameter of `sleep` (in seconds).

Comment: I think the issue is in the python script not the shell command!